# Using static library from Visual Studio 2008 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I am working to move a large project from Visual studio 2008 (Platform toolset v90) to Visual Studio 2010 (Platform toolset v100)

The project relies on a library compiled with the v90 toolset. This library is largely written in C with a single c++ class which makes use of std:string in a few places. Unfortunately this usage is preventing me from compiling with the library linked due to changes in the toolset

I removed the library name from the errors:

```
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_?erase@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@II@Z)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (__imp_?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const *)" (__imp_??4?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@PBD@Z)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator=(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??4?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z)
 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ)
```

Is there any thing I can do to compile this library under platform toolset v100? The library is proprietary so there is no way for me to get the source and recompile myself.

Comment: Contact the vendor and see if they have a version of the library built with VC++10

Comment: I think the only way you will manage to do it is to make a DLL in VC2008 that contains the static library and offer a C style interface to whatever functionality you need from it.  You'll then need to distribute the runtime for both 2008 and 2010.

Comment: @Pete 2008 runtime may not be necessary if the runtime is staticly linked into the dll.

Comment: Yes static link may help, however the use of std::string will be inconsistent and OP will have to put that library in a dll with a C style interface otherwise there is likely to be ODR violation and random crashes (if it were to build at all).

Comment: This has little to do with changes in the "toolset", everything to do with changes in the C++ standard library included with VS2010.  If you can't get the static library updated then you are solidly stuck on VS2008.  With VS2012 released a while ago and VS2013 coming soon, all with heavy changes in the C++ standard library due to C++11, this is a pita that will keep byting you if you don't address the core problem.  Never take a dependency on a static library that isn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getting a VC2010 version of the library is out of the question, then you will need to build a DLL using VS2008 that offers the functionality in the VS2008 static library.

You will probably not be able to use C++ linkage to this DLL and certainly will not be able to pass std::string directly between the DLL and your main application.  This is because the memory layout/interface is different and you will end up with ODR violations and crashes etc (that's if you can even compile/link it that way without tons of errors).

So, you'll need to craft a C style API that the DLL exposes for use by your main VS2010 application.  Strings will need to be passed as c-style `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` strings, or some other struct/opaque pointer.

If you can build the DLL in such a way that it is statically linked to the VS2008 runtime then it will ease deployment, otherwise you will need to distribute both the VS2008 and VS2010 runtime with your application installer in whatever manner you choose.